# How to show the progress dialog when call Geocoder methods

Tags: android, google-maps, progressdialog, google-geocoder

I am trying to get `latitude` `longitude` of list of address using this method

```
public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress){

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity());
    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        // May throw an IOException
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null || address.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        Address location = address.get(0);
        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return p1;
}
```

and I called this method inside the for loop, I want to show progress dialog till all `latitude` `longitude` points are receiving but my progress dialog not showing. I assume this may because of different threads can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Progress bar will not show up because the time taken to receive latitude and longitude takes fraction of milli seconds and will give no time to load the progress bar.

Comment: no this function call inside the for loop and to get all the lat and long values it takes more than 20seconds